Negative association conditioned on range of sum
Suppose that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are marginally independent random variables. Then conditionally given $S := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, it can be shown that $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ are negatively associated. To be clear, negative association is defined as below.
Definition: $X_1, \ldots, X_k$ are said to be negatively associated if for any two disjoint subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$ of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$,
$$Cov(f_1(X_i, i\in A_1), f_2(X_j, j\in A_2)) \leq 0$$
for any two increasing functions $f_1$ and $f_2$.
More properties (and in particular, the proof of the result mentioned at the beginning) of negative association can be found in the article titled "Negative Association of Random Variables, with Applications" by Kumar Joag-Dev and Frank Proschan.
My question is whether $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ are negatively associated conditionally given $\{S>t\}$ for any non-trivial $t$? Please note that, unlike conditioning on $\{S=s\}$ in the beginning, I am conditioning on $\{S>t\}$ here.
Edit: For my use case, each of the random variables follow Gaussian distribution marginally.
